# Unexpected behavior of req()

Tags: r, shiny

I experienced an unexpected behavior of my R shiny code and I'm asking myself if this is bug or if I don't understand how `req()` works.

I have an app where the user first uploads a *.txt file containing data with a location id, a date, and other data. Then the user has to choose two numerical values. The data is checked for NAs in the col date. If there are no NAs a text should appear telling the user everything is fine.

Below are two versions of my code. In `output$txt <- renderText({` I use `req()` to test if all inputs are set and the file is loaded.

The differences between the two codes are the ordering of the last two arguments in `req`. Whereas in the first version, the green text appears already when  both numeric inputs are set even the file is not uploaded, the second code behaves as expected; the user has to choose the numeric value and has to choose a file before the green bar with text appears.

Why makes the ordering of the arguments in `req()` a difference?

Code 1:

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

# UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
      wellPanel(

        fileInput("file1", label = h4("file upload")),  
        numericInput("in1", label = h4("first input"),value = 2.5, step=0.5),
        numericInput("in2", label = h4("second input"),value = NULL, step=0.5)
      )
    ),
    column(8, 

       h4(textOutput("txt"), tags$style(type="text/css", "#txt {vertical-align:top;align:center;color:#000000;background-color: #4cdc4c;}")),
       h2(""),
       textOutput("fileinfo"),
       tableOutput("tab_data")
    )
  )
)

# SERVER 
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$txt <- renderText({

    req(input$in1, input$in2, fl_data(), input$file1)

    "your data is ok and you have chosen input 1 and 2"
  })

  fl_data <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$file1 != "", "upload data and choose input 1 and 2...") 
    )

    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      dd <- read.table(inFile$datapath, sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
      dd[,2] <- ymd(dd[,2])
      if (sum(is.na(dd[,2]))>0) dd <- NULL
    }

  })

  output$tab_data <- renderTable({head(fl_data()[,1:4])})

  output$fileinfo <- renderPrint({input$file1})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Code 2:

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

# UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
      wellPanel(

        fileInput("file1", label = h4("file upload")),  
        numericInput("in1", label = h4("first input"),value = 2.5, step=0.5),
        numericInput("in2", label = h4("second input"),value = NULL, step=0.5)
      )
    ),
    column(8, 

       h4(textOutput("txt"), tags$style(type="text/css", "#txt {vertical-align:top;align:center;color:#000000;background-color: #4cdc4c;}")),
       h2(""),
       textOutput("fileinfo"),
       tableOutput("tab_data")
    )
  )
)

# SERVER 
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$txt <- renderText({

    req(input$in1, input$in2, input$file1, fl_data())

    "your data is ok and you have chosen input 1 and 2"
  })

  fl_data <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$file1 != "", "upload data and choose input 1 and 2...") 
    )

    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      dd <- read.table(inFile$datapath, sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
      dd[,2] <- ymd(dd[,2])
      if (sum(is.na(dd[,2]))>0) dd <- NULL
    }

  })

  output$tab_data <- renderTable({head(fl_data()[,1:4])})

  output$fileinfo <- renderPrint({input$file1})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

`req` short-circuits, just like the `&&` and `||` operators. As soon as it comes across an unavailable value (args evaluated left-to-right), it stops the reactive chain and doesn't care about any further args.

In the second example, `input$file1` prevents `fl_data()` from ever executing if missing, so the validation in `fl_data` never occurs. But rather than order the `req` args like in the first example, I would just remove the check for `input$file1` in `output$txt`, as it's already being checked in `fl_data`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by 'an unavailable value'? A variable that is NULL or NA? Just for my understanding. Running the first code with the unexpected behavior. If the a user selects the second input before choosing a file, the first and second arguments in `req` are truthy. The third and fourth are NULL and thus falsy. Hence the text shouldn't be rendered.

Comment: Doing some further examination I commented the `validate(need` statement and the code behaved like expected. With `validate(need` it seems that `fl_data()`is not NULL if no file is chosen and  `validate(need` is true, ie. prints 'upload data...` is passed instead of NULL. Then it seems that the error from `validate(need` breaks the evaluation of `req` after `fl_data()`, doesn't evaluate `input$file1` (which is still NULL), but renders then the text. Is that really expected?

Comment: Check the docs to see what's considered "truthy" or "available": https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html

Comment: `validate` works just like `req`. If there's a validation failure, `validate` will throw an error and stop execution of the current expression. So yes, `validate` should break the evaluation of `req` if it errors out first.

Comment: If you'd like to get into more detail, you can check the source code for `req` and `validate`. Both call `shiny:::reactiveStop` upon finding falsy items, which is basically a `base::stop` call